# Counting String occurence(s) / Enumerating occurrence(s) in the list

Tags: python

I need to update the list(s) as shown below

```
l=['hey','alan','hey','hey','hey','alan']
```

and result must be

```
l=['hey','alan','hey1','hey2','hey3','alan1']
```

My code:

```
test = int(input())
texts=[]
for i in range(test):
    texts.append(input())
res=[]
for i in texts:
    if i in res:
       # print(i)
        c=res.count(i)
        o=i+str(c)
        res.append(o)
    else:
        res.append(i)

print(res)
```

Actual output:

```
['hey', 'hey1', 'hey1']
```

expected output:

```
['hey', 'hey1', 'hey2']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test = int(input())
l=[]

for i in range(test):
  l.append(input())
res=[]
for i in range(len(l)):
   count =l[:i].count(l[i])
   if count==0:
      res.append(l[i])
   else:
      res.append(l[i]+str(count))
print(res)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary to keep a count of the occurrences:

```
l = ['hey', 'alan', 'hey', 'hey', 'hey', 'alan']

d = {}
result = []
for key in l:
    result.append(f'{key}{d[key]}' if key in d else key)
    if key not in d:
        d[key] = 0
    d[key] += 1

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['hey', 'alan', 'hey1', 'hey2', 'hey3', 'alan1']
```

Comment: This doesn't solve problem user is having with code. Its a totally different solution which leads to expected output but not useful for user.

Comment: @Poojan IMHO while this does not solve the particular problem of the OP, is a valid solution, that someone searching for something similar can find useful

Answer (score 0):

- you need to add original string into `res` to keep count.
- i suggest create another array for this. `cnt`.
- Because after second iteration of `hey`. you will have `res = ['hey', 'hey1']` and for next hey count of `hey` in res still stays `1`.

```
test = int(input())
texts=[]
for i in range(test):
    texts.append(input())
res=[]
cnt=[]
for i in texts:
    if i in res:
       # print(i)
        c=cnt.count(i)
        o=i+str(c)
        res.append(o)
        cnt.append(i)
    else:
        res.append(i)
        cnt.append(i)

print(res)
```

ps: Your method is not most optimal method to do the task. I suggest using `Counter` for this.

```
from collections import Counter
test = int(input())
texts=[]
for i in range(test):
    texts.append(input())
c = Counter(texts)
res = []
for x,y in c.items():
    for i in range(y):
        res.append(x if i==0 else x+str(i))

print(res)
```

- output

> ['hey', 'hey1', 'hey2', 'hey3', 'alan', 'alan1']

Answer (score 0):

this version with DataFrame usage:

```
l1 = ['hey','alan','hey','hey','hey','alan']

df = pd.DataFrame(l1, columns = ['name'])

Out[1]:
    name
0   hey 
1   alan
2   hey 
3   hey 
4   hey 
5   alan

df['num'] = df.groupby(['name']).cumcount()

Out[2]:
    name    num
0   hey     0
1   alan    0
2   hey     1
3   hey     2
4   hey     3
5   alan    1


df['num_name'] = [(lambda x: x[0] + (str(x[1]) if x[1]!=0 else ''))(s) for s in zip(df['name'], df['num'])]

Out[3]:
    name    num num_name
0   hey     0   hey
1   alan    0   alan
2   hey     1   hey1
3   hey     2   hey2
4   hey     3   hey3
5   alan    1   alan1

list(df['num_name'])

Out[4]:
['hey', 'alan', 'hey1', 'hey2', 'hey3', 'alan1']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this pretty simply by just counting the number of occurrences of each element of the list while iterating through it, and appending the count for all the occurrences past 0:

```
out = [] 
for i,word in enumerate(l):
    count = l[:i].count(word)
    if count == 0:
        out.append(word)
    else:
        out.append(word+str(count))
```

out:

```
['hey', 'alan', 'hey1', 'hey2', 'hey3', 'alan1']
```

Comment: thanks mate..!
i found another way without using enumerate